# Start at ultimate right in an infinite ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that I want to give a theoretically infinite amount of pages. Every page contains a text linked to a date, and swiping the user should be able to see texts from previous dates. He can't see texts for future dates.

To do this, I gave the `ViewPager` as count `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. However, I want the default page to be the ultimate right one, so that swiping left can show texts for previous dates. By default, the first position is ultimately left.

This is my code:

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new DailyTextFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

I have tried do `setCurrentPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, but then Android attempts to compute all pages *before* the last one, which is many, and I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

I have thought about tricking the `ViewPager` into thinking the x-coordinate of touch events is mirrored, but don't know exactly **how to do that** or **if that is the best solution**. What would be the best way to set up this kind of interface?

Comment: don't instantiate a fragment every time is called. The Fragment *could* be one, you have to update the content

Comment: @Blackbelt that sounds like a good idea (although there would still be something looping 0 .. INT_MAX). What do you mean exactly with "The Fragment _could_ be one"?

Comment: I have never done it. I am not sure if it is not going to work

Comment: @Blackbelt it wouldn't hurt to try, but I don't understand your second sentence, so I can't try :) could you perhaps give a small code example to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: oh, I thought something like, you keep it a member. The first time getItem is called, the member is null. You instantiate it and return it. If it is not null, you have to update the content

Comment: @Blackbelt hm, thanks, but when I do that (i.e. have the Fragment as a property of the adapter, and return that if it has been instantiated already) it gives me a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added` - I think it's not possible to add exactly the same Fragment twice...

Comment: Yeah, you can't have just a single `Fragment` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` -- it'll want at least 3. My guess is that you will need to create a `PagerAdapter` of your own that can implement your rule set better.

Comment: interesting, why is 3 the magic number? is it because of the off screen limit ? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Blackbelt: Yes, that's the minimum offscreen page limit. `PagerAdapter` will want three pages too, but since you're not necessarily dealing with fragments, you may have greater flexibility to fake things. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare alright, it's just that I have no clue how to do this concretely. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have not looked into creating an infinite `ViewPager`, let alone one that starts at infinity and works its way backwards. At minimum, you'd need to create a custom subclass of `PagerAdapter`, and it would not shock me if you might wind up tweaking `ViewPager` itself via a fork. Creating a custom `PagerAdapter` implementation, at its core, is not that hard (see [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1)). Creating a custom `PagerAdapter` that uses fragments is a pain (see [CWAC-Pager](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager))

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your help anyway. It turns out by the way that it doesn't attempt to load Integer.MAX_VALUE times a `DailyTextFragment()` in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` it does: `while (mFragments.size() <= position) mFragments.add(null);`, and the `ArrayList` can't handle that many items. Maybe I can make a different version of that `instantiateItem()` method, and do something clever with this (so that I can keep using fragments, and don't have to change the rest of the code). But now I have to go, I'll try it later.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got it working, and added an answer. I'm not that familiar with this stuff though. Perhaps you could review it to see if this is fine (and that I won't run into weird problems later)? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging, I found out the following:

- When you try to set `setCurrentPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, the `FragmentStatePageAdapter` will attempt to make an `ArrayList` of 2147483647 NULL objects. Because of this, you run out of memory.
- In fact, only the first two fragments (0 and 1) are instantiated: the rest of the `ArrayList` are NULL values.

This is implemented in `instantiateItem()` as follows:

```
while (mFragments.size() <= position) {
    mFragments.add(null);
}
```

Now, what we can do is tricking the `FragmentStatePageAdapter` by overriding this method as follows:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (position < 2) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    } else {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, Integer.MAX_VALUE - position - 1);
    }
}
```

So, for the first two objects we give the super method the real number - for the other objects, we give it `Integer.MAX_VALUE - position`. Now, you can safely do this in the `onCreate` method of your activity, for example:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE, false);
```

Like this, the `ViewPager` will start at the ultimate right, using object 0. So, your objects are reversed: object 0 is the last one, on the far right, and further to the left your fragments have an increasing index.

You also need to override `destroyItem()`, because it has the same loop to add NULL values. Like this:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if (position < 2) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    } else {
        super.destroyItem(container, Integer.MAX_VALUE - position - 1, object);
    }
}
```

This is probably not the preferred way of doing this, but it's working for me.

Comment: Well, on the whole, this sort of solution makes me as nervous as a long-tailed cat in a room full of rocking chairs (h/t to Foghorn Leghorn). In theory, I suspect you'll have problems if the user did navigate all the way to the right. In practice, that ain't happening. If it is working for you, more power to you.